# how do i get form data in a static page in silverstripe

Tags: php, forms, silverstripe

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but the situation is that I have a page in silverstripe (static) called 'PageX' with a form in it. It is managed by the controller in the file PageX.php. My question is how to get the data from the form in the controller. I thought that could be done just with the action and then allowing that action in the controller and a public function with the same name, but instead tries to redirect to that page. Help?

Comment: what have you tried? have you read this? https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/forms/introduction/

Comment: so, i load a file .ss with a hardcoded form and i want to get the data submitted and send it somewhere (this last bit is not relevant). so with the controller that loads the .ss with the form, i tried to get the form data, but i can't because the actions redirect me to a page with the name of the action. so the question is simple, is there a way to handle form submissions without going through all the Form class??

Comment: i tried that but since is a static page and there's no need to use the cms, i can't find the way to make it work

Comment: or if im gonna use the form class, then how to add text between the input fields, and also how to add divs to wrap the whole thing for the css to make the desired effect

Comment: You should post your code to make it a bit clearer. By hard coded form, do you mean you put code such as `<form><input type="text" name="firstname"><input type="surname"></form>` into the template rather than using a SilverStripe form? If this is the case, I would be looking at the request object. http://api.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/class-SS_HTTPRequest.html In the index function of your controller, you could do something like `if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {  // do something with the form values }`.

Comment: Or you could even just add functions to your controller such as `function FirstName() { return $this->getRequest()->getVar('firstname'); }` and then in your template, use `$FirstName`. Its pretty messy and you should really look into using SilverStripe form.

Comment: @GavinBruce yes, that is what i was trying to do!